# How to create postgresql table VIEW while using a placeholder variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having trouble creating a view for my SELECT statement. I use a placeholder variable like so, to query a script that pulls data based on a list of stocks inputted by the user. I want to make this a view, rather than a select. However I'm having trouble getting the function to work with placeholders.

Is it even possible?

```
CREATE VIEW dividend_dates AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol) symbol,
                            next_dividend_date,
                            ex_dividend_date
                            FROM api.security_stats 
                            WHERE api.security_stats.symbol 
                            IN ({placeholders}) 
                            ORDER BY symbol, date desc;
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Views don't accept such parameters.

Comment: You can write a function to do the query including the parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I will research functions! Much obliged!

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL.